# #!/usr/bin/env php running orm:schema-tool:create

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've installed Doctrine using composer, and when I try to create the database I get the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Why am I seeing this error - no database is created. I obtain the same error if I run update --force. I've also tried orm:schema-tool:create, and I've also tried running the doctrine php file directly `php ./vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:schema:create` with the same error.

I have an bootstrap file and a cli-config file as such

// bootstrap.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

// cli-config.php

```
<?php
require_once "bootstrap.php";
return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging, the path in this line is horribly wrong:

```
$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/"), $isDevMode);
```

Fixing it so it points to where the class files with mapping data is stored fixed it.